# Update JSONB column with NULL value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I'm trying to update the following `y.data`, which is a JSONB type column that currently contains a NULL value. The `||` command does not seem to work merging together `y.data` with `x.data` when `x.data` is NULL. It works fine when `x.data` contains a JSONB value.

Here is an example query.

```
UPDATE x
SET x.data = y.data::jsonb || x.data::jsonb
FROM (VALUES ('2018-05-24', 'Nicholas', '{"test": "abc"}')) AS y (post_date, name, data)
WHERE x.post_date::date = y.post_date::date AND x.name = y.name;
```

What would be the best way to modify this query to support updating `x.data` for rows that both have existing values or are NULL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concatenating anything with `null` produces `null`. You can use `coalesce()` or conditional logic to work around this:

```
SET x.data = COALESCE(y.data::jsonb || x.data, y.data::jsonb)
```

Or:

```
SET x.data = CASE WHEN x.data IS NULL 
    THEN y.data::jsonb
    ELSE y.data::jsonb || x.data
END
```

Note that there is no need to explictly cast `x.data` to `jsonb`, since it's a `jsonb` column already.

Comment: I worked out the CASE solution you posted for myself, but the COALESCE solution is shorter, clearer, and therefore the preferred answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL it is best to assume as a general rule that adding NULL to something makes the whole thing NULL. To deal with the above try something like:

```
test(5432)=# SELECT '[1, 2, "foo", null]'::jsonb || null;
 ?column? 
----------
 NULL

SELECT '[1, 2, "foo", null]'::jsonb || coalesce(NULL, '[]'::jsonb);
      ?column?       
---------------------
 [1, 2, "foo", null]
```

The COALESCE supplies something to the `||` that is `NOT NULL`. If you want something different then modify question to indicate.